# Having issues with passing session variables with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand session variables by trying this code. For the purpose of the test, I created 3 pages and tried to pass the session variables around. I noticed that, the session variable is not populated in the 3rd page. I have searched to see where the problem is and I'm yet to figure it out.

<kbd>page1</kbd>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Bio Data</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <form action="process.php" method="post">
            <label for="fst_name">
                First Name
                <input type="text" name="fst_name" id="fst_name">
            </label>

            <label for="lst_name">
                Last Name
                <input type="text" name="lst_name" id="lst_name">
            </label>

            <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

<kbd>page2</kbd>

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){           
    $_SESSION['fst_name'] = $_POST['fst_name'] ;
    $_SESSION['lst_name' ] = $_POST['lst_name'] ;
    header("location:display.php");
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

<kbd>page3</kbd>

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['fst_name'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Biodata Display</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo "Hello " .  $_SESSION['fst_name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $_SESSION['lst_name']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this looks allright to me.. have you tested if you have `$_SESSION['fst_name']` in page2 with the expected value, or does $_POST have the expected values?

Comment: *"the session variable is not populated in the 3rd page"* - Which one, you have two and can't see where you've assigned anything to `$_SESSION['last']`.

Comment: @Jeff `$_SESSION['fst_name`] have values on page2. @Fred-ii- I have corrected the code. None of the session variable appears on page3.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions in PHP work by saving a data file server side referenced by a special cookie (by default named PHPSESSID), so when your browser sends the proper cookie PHP fetches from the saved data files the previous $_SESSION value. This means that:

1. Your server must be able to **write** files (usually in tmp dir, check PHP INI settings related to session save path
2. Your browser must accept cookies (you can easily check this by dumping $_COOKIE)

To simplify your test, create a single page like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
var_dump($_COOKIE);
var_dump($_SESSION);
$_SESSION['hello'] = "world";
```

After you load this page TWICE, you should see the right data in $_SESSION and $_COOKIE. If it doesn't work, your problem is in your server/environment. If that works, I'll look again at your code but it looked fine on first sight.

Comment: I'm to see the data in $_SESSION on the page2. I really don't know why it's appearing in page3.